# Why file executing are prefixed with dot and slash?

Tags: command-line

Why to execute a shell script I have to write:

```
./shell
```

why can't I execute it just using

```
shell
```

being in the directory with the file?

Comment: There is an explanation on Unix SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432

Answer (score 0):

Because the directory you are in is not in your PATH.

---

What you want is possible with ...

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

You could add this to wherever you currently have your PATH set but a fair warning: this is a potential security risk because you could replace standard commands like `ls`. Never ever put the "." in front of any other directory. NEVER.

Comment: but in windows if i am in the directory with the file, i can execute it, why in ubuntu it not like this?

Comment: Because we take security serious.